# The lcm of $p,q$ is $r^2t^4s^2$ where $p,q,r,s,t$ are natural numbers. Find the number of ordered pairs $(p,q)$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> The lcm of $p,q$ is $r^2t^4s^2$ where $p,q,r,s,t$ are natural numbers and $r,s,t$ are primes. Find the number of ordered pairs $(p,q)$.

I consider the set {${r,r,t,t,t,t,s,s}$} .I think the number of subsets of the set is the answer which is $2^8=256$.I am not sure about my approach.Can anyone solve this ?
Thank you in advance!

Edit: Suppose $r,s,t$ are fixed primes!

N.E.: It is a problem from the chapter 'elementary-set theory' .So you can this problem as a set-theoretic problem

Comment: Are $r, s$ and $t$ prime?

Comment: Yeah they are prime

Comment: Sorry about my answer; I wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a countable infinity.  Find any single pair $(p,q)$ that satisfies the requirement.  I would just choose $p=1, q=r^2s^4t^2$ because it is easy to find.  You can choose $r,s,t$ to be any primes you want.

For fixed $r,s,t$ you need each of $p=r^as^bt^c,q=r^ds^et^f$ with $\max(a,d)=2$ and so on.  How many choices for $a,d$?  Count them and multiply.

Comment: I asked for the number of such ordered pairs!

Comment: It is in the first sentence.  There are as many as the naturals.  The set of primes is infinite.

Comment: Suppose $r,s,t$ are fixed primes!

Comment: You have made two major changes to the question.  Please think about the question and make sure you have it right before posting.